# In model association, is there any difference between parent.childs.build vs parent.build_child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

As far as usage is concerned, I've used `parent.childs.build` and `parent.build_child` interchangeably. Is it okay to use the two methods interchangeably?

If there is difference between the two methods, what situation is each method used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `build_child` is used in a `has_one` situation, and `children.build` is used in a `has_many`.

There's no real difference here though -- they will each build a new object (but not save it), and set the new object's parent_id to the parent

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, they refer to the same method. Rails just put it at both locations for convenience.